# Replace spaces between letters only

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file with columns of numbers and letters:

```
0.01182290 0.02526555 0.46794573 RING zinc finger protein putative 0105800 1076 1166 -90
```

I want to replace the spaces between the letters to underscores.

```
0.01182290 0.02526555 0.46794573 RING_zinc_finger_protein_putative 0105800 1076 1166 -90
```

Im new to regex, the substitute string is `[a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z]`, but I can't figure what the replacement is. Everything I tried changes the letters between the spaces.

```
:%s/[a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z]/??/g/
```

Comment: "between" => "around" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
:%s/\v(\a)\s(\a)/\1_\2/g
```

The idea here is to use capturing groups and put their captured value in the output.

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler alternative would be to make use of vim's start of match and end of match atoms (`\zs` and `\ze`):

```
:%s/\a\zs\s\ze\a/_/g
```

Breakdown:

- `:%s/` - Start of the substitution command for the entire file
- `\a` - Shorthand for `[A-Za-z]`
- `\zs` - Start of match string
- `\s` - Space or Tab
- `\ze` - End of match string
- `\a` - Same as above
- `/_/` - Replace the match string with an `_`
- `g` - For each occurrence on the line

Comment: Thanks for the `\a`. I ported that part to my own answer.