# How to replace spaces between words using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to convert a string of words and numbers into a list, every item is separated with a space, so using .replace(" ", ",").split(",") would be an easy solution, but unfortunately, sometimes there are multiple words in the object name, and I would like these words to be connected with a _

Example:

```
office supplies 674.56 570.980487 755.84 682.360029
```

Expected output:

```
office_supplies 674.56 570.980487 755.84 682.360029
```

I have found this:
[Replace spaces between letters only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418372/replace-spaces-between-letters-only)

And tried to implement it like this:

```
sample_line = "office supplies 674.56 570.980487 755.84 682.360029"
regex = re.compile(':%s/\v(\a)\s(\a)/\1_\2/g', re.I)
print(re.sub(p, r"\1\2", line))
```

But it does not seem to replace the spaces, I am not very sharp with regex, but according to the linked issue, it should work.

Comment: What you've found i `vim` solution not python

Comment: `\D\s\D` should look for whitespaces between non-digit characters https://regex101.com/r/t0kOKw/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may probably use this `re.sub + split` solution:

```py
import re
s = 'office supplies 674.56 570.980487 755.84 682.360029'
print ( re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])', '_', s).split() )
```

**Output:**

```py
['office_supplies', '674.56', '570.980487', '755.84', '682.360029']
```

Here:

- Regex `(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])` matches 1+ whitespace surrounded with letters only
- `split` will split string on whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

```
x=r'office supplies 674.56 570.980487 755.84 682.360029'
lead="_".join(x.split()[:2])
trail=" ".join(x.split()[2:])

expected_string = lead + " " + trail
print(expected_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue got solved already 